# display hello in uitableview cell in swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as UITableViewCell!
    cell.textLabel?.text = "hello"
    return cell
}
```

I get fatal error

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

Comment: Is that a custom cell ? Are you getting added that in Storyboard and added reuse identifier properly ?

Comment: What do you expect? you are force unwrapping the cell, which is likely to fail if you haven't registered a cell or a nib file for that identifier.

Comment: no It is not a custom cell

Comment: @abizern : It is not giving error at the time of creating cell but It is giveing me fatal error at the time of assigning values

Comment: @VikramKThakor: Which your cell type ? And check whether the cell is nil or not. Reuse Identifier in prototype cell is correct or not

Answer (score 1):

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell:UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as UITableViewCell

        cell.textLabel?.text = "hello"

        return cell
    }
```

Comment: Can you explain why the above code crashed and how your code won't cause the crash ?

Comment: var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as UITableViewCell!

This line having difference.

Comment: Yes, that I saw. But what is the difference between those ? Why it differs ?

Comment: Your reuseIdentifier ("Cell") is capitalized and his isn't.

Comment: Its regarding `wrape` and `unwrape` functionality which is supported in `swift`

Answer (score 0):

As [Abhishek Sharma](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4284346/abhishek-sharma) mentioned in the comments above, your error is being caused by the unwrapping of an optional value returning nil, whereas your code expects a non-nil value.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

var cell: UITableViewCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as? UITableViewCell
cell?.textLabel?.text = "hello"
return cell!

}
```